# Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters';

Tags: spring-batch

Getting this error while

Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

This is how I'm adding JobParameters to my tasklet

JobService.java
private final JobLauncher asyncJobLauncher;

final JobParameters jobParams = mpsJobParameters.createJobParameters(parameters);
final JobExecution execution = asyncJobLauncher.run(job, jobParams);

JobParametersFactory.java

```
`public JobParameters createJobParameters(BulkJobParameters bulkParams) {
        try {
            JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
            jobParametersBuilder.addJobParameter(KEY_BULK_ID, createBulkIdentifierParameter(bulkParams.getBulkRequestId()));
            jobParametersBuilder.addJobParameter(KEY_USER_NAME, createNonIdParam(bulkParams.getUserName()));
            jobParametersBuilder.addJobParameter(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME, createNonIdParam(bulkParams.getDisplayName()));
            final String requestAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(bulkParams.getRequest());
            jobParametersBuilder.addJobParameter(KEY_REQUEST, createNonIdParam(requestAsString));
            return new JobParameters(jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters().getParameters());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Failure serializing request {}", bulkParams.getRequest(), e);
            throw new BulkJobException(e, bulkParams.getRequest());
        }
    }
`
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
`public CustomAdapter(     ServerSideEventRegistration sseRegistry,
                                            ExportStoreManager storeManager,
                                            @Value("#{jobParameters}") JobParameters parameters) {`
`
```

This is where I'm getting the error :
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.CustomAdapter' defined in file [****]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 6: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

My batch job is getting executed but failing with the above error

Answer (score 0):

Try to annotate CustomAdapter with @StepScop

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).